# Handling huge text files to extract content : Java; groovy or better go Linux scripting (awk,grep)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, text-parsing

Calling to some previous experience in taming text files. My requirements is to parse some unformatted text files.

I see older questions on these topics but didn't found one targeting my concern. I know it can be done in any of the tools I have mentioned, more or less easily , with pros and cons.

What I'm asking for, is recommendation from your experiences in the context of an deployed WAR so I will let the best tool do the job.

So what is to be done ? There it is :

1. In an plain JEE war app (java 8)
2. For all unformatted files under DIRTOPARSE
3. read the file until you enconter this < PARSE > tag (the only formatted contents [as -quite- well formed xml] in the files.
4. take everything between < PARSE > and < /PARSE >
5. bring it into a xml document
6. then from there there will be some processing to populate part of an plain JEE WAR application (can be jaxb or something like that, I didn't decided yet for that part as it will the easiest part of the job)

I'm calling to some experience because the files can be(quite) huge and I'm concerned about the most efficient ways to handle such requirements as Java is not with good reputation as a tool for large text handling... should I use another jvm dialect (Groovy?) or should I go and do all the text parts (steps **1 to 4**) under some Linux tools (which really have the good reputation or such things) **bash, grep, awk, perl**?

Based on your help, I will test and pseudo-benchmark to select what seems to fit.

Comment: How huge they can be?

Comment: Well, as it goes I don't think they will get that big !  First sample I got they are around 2 and 3 Mo.So even if this is not the kind of tasks well suited for Java I will first try with java .   But there will be  hundreds of them , may be the troubles will raise only on prod... ? Anyway as I start I stay tuned here and will appreciate any concrete recommendation to avoid pitfalls.